# "Крайне рады" — уместно ли так писать в Справке?

Tags: предложение

> [Мы крайне рады видеть вас на сайте!](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Зачем же впадать в "крайности"? Не лучше ли написать: "Мы очень рады видеть вас на сайте!"?

Comment: Ваш звонок очень важен для нас. )))))